# Clean Many2one field

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

hello I have a `many2one` object and would like to delete the data found in another `many2one`, but the method does not work

```
<field name="bodega_id" 
       colspan="2" 
       context="{'picking_types_from_user':True}"
       on_change="onchange_bodega(bodega_id)"/>
```

Method

```
def onchange_bodega(self, cr, uid, ids, bodega_id=False, context=None):return {
    'value': {'producto_requerimiento_ids': False}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope it's work for you:

return {'value': {'producto_requerimiento_ids': [('id', '=', False)]}}

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgraded the module after you made changes.